# React Fetch On Event - Best Practices

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, design-patterns

Our team is new to React, and we are learning best practices as we go.

One of the teams biggest concerns right now is how we are handling our API calls and dealing with state. We are following Reacts advice which is --> "Lift Up State". This all works, but it is causing our higher level components to be large and often handle API calls that I don't think it should have to be concerned with.

The below example is very simplified. In reality each of these fetch statements will need to set the state of a few different things, such as loadingForA, statusForA, dataForA.... This quickly leads to a very large state and a lot of passing down of props

**Are there any design patterns that can be used here? I have looked into "Render Props", but this seems to be hard to use for event triggered API fetches**

Example:

```
class SelectorA extends Component {
   render(){
      return(
         <Dropdown
            onChange = {this.props.handleChange}
         >{this.props.data}</Dropdown>
         <p>{this.props.date}</p>
      )
   }


}


class App extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            date: '',
            dataA: {},
            dataB: {},
            dataC: {}
        };
    }
   handleChangeA() {
      fetch(someURL)
      .then(
         this.setState({dataA: fetchResult});
      )
    }

   handleChangeB() {
      fetch(someURL + this.state.dataA)
      .then(
         this.setState({dataB: fetchResult});
      )
   }

   handleChangeC() {
      fetch(someURL + this.state.dataC)
      .then(
         this.setState({dataC: fetchResult});
      )
   }

   render(){
      return(
         <SelectorA
             handleChange = {this.handleChangeA}

             date = {this.date}
             data = {this.dataA}
         />
         <SelectorB
             handleChange = {this.handleChangeB}

             date = {this.date}
             data = {this.dataB}
         />
         <SelectorC
             handleChange = {this.handleChangeC}

             date = {this.date}
             dataC = {this.dataC}
         />
      );
   }

}
```

Comment: I would suggest you to read properly the react documentation https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html. 
There are some bad practices here starting from the fact that you are updating the state outside a react life cycle (usually fetch api is being called inside the ComponentDidMount method. 
Considering the fact you are starting using React nowadays, I would recommend you to use React Hooks https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html so you don't have to worry about life cycles and you can use state and other React features without writing a class.

Comment: Thanks for the resposne. I have updated the example to better reflect what's actually happening. Namely we use the results of previous fetches to create the url of the next fetch (query params). I'm not sure how we could leverage the life cycle methods here to call the API on change. If I change SelectorA then how will that trigger handleChangeB?